# Markups in src/main/resources cannot be found in Wicket 7.3.0 project running on Jetty

Tags: java, apache, maven, jetty, wicket

I have created Wicket 7.3.0 project using the Quick Start Wizard.

I have moved the file `HomePage.html` into **src/main/resources** and achieved following directory structure:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtrJH.png)

This is part of the generated `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    // etc...
</build>
```

Yet when I start the application on jetty server, I get the following error:

```
Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = de.vantroba.modelview.web.HomePage, id = 0, render count = 1]
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkup(Component.java:749)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2345)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2308)
 at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems that the markup file can not be found. Can somebody tell me, what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check that HomePage.html resides next to HomePage.class in target/classes/...

Comment: I checked the folder and did not find any markups. I have then tried to clean and refresh the project. After that the markups were copied in the folder and the application works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought. I checked the **target/classes/...** folder as martin-g recommended. I did not found any markups, so I tried to **clean** and **refresh** the project and the markups were copied into that folder and the application works now.